# When upgrading hardware, do I need to reinstall elementary OS for hardware recognition?

Tags: updates, hardware, cpu

I am currently running integrated graphics with an AMD A4 7300 APU. I am looking to upgrade my system with an AMD Athlon X4 860K CPU and a Sapphire R9 270.  Do I need to reinstall elementary OS after the hardware upgrade for hardware recognition or will the new hardware be recognized?

Comment: try installing the drivers first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only main issue : your video graphic card. If you want to change your graphic card, do not forget to uninstall your driver.

Comment: So just to clarify.  The best course of action would be, while still using integrated graphics: uninstall my current video driver, install whatever driver may be needed for my new graphics card, then shutdown the computer, install the new CPU and new graphics card, then start the computer?

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to use your integrated graphic card, just uninstall the video driver, you'll return to the default video config. **Be sure to backup your system before changing everything**

Answer (score 3):

No, not usually. I have switched hard disks between different machines more than once, and that shouldn’t be a problem. The only thing to make sure beforehand might be to see whether your new hardware needs drivers that are definitely not included in the distribution you are going to use.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check what drivers are included with Elementary OS, so I can check to see if my new hardware is supported?

Comment: I am not aware of any place where you could easily check whether your particular equipment might cause trouble, other than the release notes of the distribution you’re using. A quick google search turned up a number of people who had problems with an R9 270 card. Maybe you should try asking in the G+ community whether there are people running that card on elementary and what their experiences are.